# How to draw dotted poly lines when inside the home or building in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, fluttermap

Today I was playing with Google Maps by following [this article](https://blog.codemagic.io/creating-a-route-calculator-using-google-maps/), All is good until I find out dotted poly lines is missing.Can anyone help me to draw dotted lines when origin or destination is inside building.What I have now something similar to this
[image: what I got] and this is actually what I want [image: what I want the dotted lines]
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to below code for poly line with dashed

```
      GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          markers: markers,
          polylines: {
            Polyline(
              polylineId: PolylineId('1'),
              color: ThemeColors.primary,
              width: 2,
              patterns: [
                PatternItem.dash(8),
                PatternItem.gap(15),
              ],
              points: const [
                LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
                LatLng(36.42796133580664, -123.08575),
              ],
            ),
          },
        ),
```

For more read this [article](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60083)

Comment: How to convert this dotted poly line into a projectile polyline (with curve)? like the one mentioned in second screen shot.